# antlr3: distinguish the same character in different contextes

Tags: antlr3

I need to translate simple text from this

```
Some title - possibly with dashes inside
---
other text
```

to this:

```
<h1>Some title - possibly with dashes inside</h1>
<div>other text</div>
```

in other words one or more dashes on a separate line separates the title from the other text

i made this grammar:

```
grammar Foo;
options { output=template; }

text : t+=title? -> lesson(title={$t}) ;

title : PLAIN_TEXT titleSeparator -> title(txt={$PLAIN_TEXT.text});

titleSeparator : NL '-'+ NL ;

PLAIN_TEXT : LETTER+ ;
NL  : '\r'? '\n' ;

fragment LETTER : 'a'..'z' | '-' | ' ';
```

The grammar produces correct output though throws warning: line 2:0 mismatched input '--' expecting '-'. I saw a question regarding this issue here, but it didn't help me.

I feel i'm missing something, but cannot get what exactly.

what i need is a grammar which distinguishes separate dash in a text and line consisting of several dashes

thanks in advance

Comment: The lexer grammar is ambiguous. The sequence '--' can be matched by both LETTER and the '-' token embedded in titleSeparator. Try moving the separator to the lexer (just uppercase the first letter).